# Include header file from different folder using g++

Tags: c++, terminal, header, g++

I was trying to install the FLTK library and saw header files that used a different directory. So I tried to test it out as:

```
\\check.cpp in D:\C++\
#include <factorial.h> // Self-made header file in folder D:\C++\link\
#include <iostream>
int main(){
  // Blah blah and call to factorial function from factorial.h
}
```

Do note: the link folder contains 1. string.exe (a simple EXE file) 2. factorial.h...

I am trying to compile *check.cpp* from *D:\C++* using Cygwin as:

```
g++ this.cpp -ID:\C++\link -o done.exe
```

When there is only *factorial.h* in the link folder (*D:\C++\link*), the compilation successfully completes and produces a working executable.

But when there is another file, string.exe, in the same directory, g++ tries to take the EXE file as input... The exact compile error is as:

```
In file included from

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/include/c++/bits/locale_classes.h:40:0,
                     from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/include/c++/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                     from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/include/c++/ios:42,
                     from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/include/c++/ostream:38,
                     from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/include/c++/iostream:39,
                     from check.cpp:2:
    D:\C++\link/string:1:3: error: stray ‘\220’ in program
     MZ□       □□  □       @                                   □   □ □ □!□L□!This program cannot be run in DOS mode.

       ^
    D:\C++\link/string:1:5: error: stray ‘\3’ in program
     MZ□       □□  □       @                                   □   □ □ □!□L□!This program cannot be run in DOS mode.
         ^
    D:\C++\link/string:1:9: error: stray ‘\4’ in program
     MZ□       □□  □       @                                   □   □ □ □!□L□!This program cannot be run in DOS mode.
```

As far as I can guess, using -ID:\C++\link\ tried to take *string.exe* as input or something like that...

Comment: "+" [***is*** allowed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#In_Windows) in Windows filenames...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using slashes instead of backslashes? `/` instead of `\` ?

I think what you see is the compiler trying to include string.exe when calling
`#include <string>` somewhere in `<iostream>`.

Also calling the folder 'link' is kind of confusing, 'include' would be a better name.

It looks like you are using MinGW - this may help you: [MinGW include path howto](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/IncludePathHOWTO)

Comment: Forward or Backward .. any kind of slashes works... And I am using Cygwin instead of Mingw.. And Thanks.. That suggestion of yours worked like a charm.. I didn't realized preprocessor would try to include string.exe during the call of <string>.